# Proving recurrence relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

So, I initially proved the theorem that if $a  != b^d$ and $n$ is a power of $b$, then $f(n) =
C_1n^d + C_2n^{log_b a}$, where $C_1 = b^dc/(b^d − a)$ and $C_2 =
f(1) + b^dc/(a − b^d )$.

This is seen here, for those who are interested: [image: proof]

What I want to know is how to show that if $a > b^d$, then $f(n)$ is $O(n^{log_ba})$?

Thank you!

Comment: How do you get $f(n)=af(n/b)+cn^d$ in the beginning of your inductive step ?

Comment: Do you think that is wrong?

Comment: I didn't say it's wrong, just that I don't understand where it comes from. The only thing you know about the function $f$ is from the lemma you're trying to prove. In other words, at that time of the proof the only thing you can use about $f$ is its value for $n=b^k$, you can't say anything about its value for $n=b^{k+1}$. However, you might have some other information about $f$ that I don't know about, but for now I really don't see how you could possibly get this relation having no other information than what's in your post.

Comment: Wow, well if it changes things, that shouldn't be $a! = b^d$ it should be $a$ $!=$ $b^d$..

Comment: @Dolma Here is the image showing the proof in its entirety.  Please let me know if there is something that appears wrong from this: http://gyazo.com/4dc761cba2cdeea403a30ef77cfa225b.png?1366840613

Comment: Here's prior knowledge as well: http://gyazo.com/f545de518d64df5a000715a26015a68d.png?1366840691

Comment: @Dolma Tell me if this is more accurate, please! http://gyazo.com/5de500055fda53a0691529bd93b3ac5d.png?1366840932

Comment: Oh ok, well then there's no problem. It says: "assume that $f$ is a function satisfying $f(n)=af(n/b)+cn^d$". Since it is something you assume, there's no point in wondering whether it's true or false, it's neither, it's just something you assume, so it's true in some sense (in the context of your proof) ;)

Comment: I guess what you mean is that the first proof didn't mention we should assume that? Haha

Answer (score 1):

If $a > b^{d}$ then $\log_{b}a > \log_{b}b^{d} = d$.

Hence $n^{d} < n^{\log_{b}a}$

and so

$C_{1}n^{d} + C_{2}n^{\log_{b}a} < (C_{1} + C_{2})n^{\log_{b}a}$,

so $f(n)$ is $O(n^{\log_{b}a})$.